# Communication between two iOS devices

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, communication

I am looking for a way to have one iPhone app send a message to another app on a different phone (sort of like a Sender-Receiver set up). I am looking for the best possible way to do this. Does anyone have any ideas and/or tutorials?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Locally or remote?  In other words, are the two devices in the same room, or anywhere on the planet?

Comment: @user1205480:please describe your question well. else others can't identify what you are looking for.

Comment: The phones are in the general area, i.e. same building.

Answer (score 17):

You should use GameKit. It is super easy to send messages between two iOS devices using it. Here's a great tutorial: [Game Kit](http://imagineric.ericd.net/2011/04/20/ios-gamekit-iphone-to-iphone-communication/). You can also get more information about it here from the docs: [About Game Kit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

You communicate by creating an ad-hoc bluetooth or local wireless network.

Comment: The tutorial above worked PERFECTLY. I had a working prototype in less than 5 minutes.

Comment: How much overhead in terms of memory does GameKit introduce? (IMHO this is  always something that you should ask yourself when using a 3rd party library.)

Comment: The first link is dead. The second link works badly on iOS; can't tell if that's the content or my device.

Answer (score 4):

lmirak provided  insightful info about device communication(especially about GameKit). I would like to add one more solution. You can use **WiFi** network to do your device communication.

See the link or  download the sample application from [developer.apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WiTap/Introduction/Intro.html)

The sample application named as WiTap. It demonstrates how to achieve network communication between applications. Using Bonjour, the application both advertises itself on the local network and displays a list of other instances of this application on the network.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is only going to run on iOS, then you should use the fantastic **MultipeerConnectivity** library. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity

---

If you need a solution that will work cross-platform, then one way to accomplish this is using sockets and connecting over a local network. On iOS you can use CocoaAsyncPods for sockets and NetService for discovery.

Here is a basic example app that does this: https://github.com/brendaninnis/LocalNetworkingApp
, which I explain in great detail here: http://brendaninnis.ca/connect-nearby-devices-part-1.html